# How do I get the accent-key feature to work with Java based applications?

Tags: java, fedora, compose-key

I'm using Fedora 18 with Gnome 3.6, my keyboard layout settings is English (US). 
When I need to write accented characters, I use the compose key (right-alt) plus the accent key (`) followed by the vowel I want to be accented. It works fine in all applications except in those that are java based.
Anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Comment: How is the compose key defined? I have another setup (Debian/KDE), but compose does work here in java applicatiosn when defined via ~/.Xmodmap: `keysym Super_R = Multi_key` (that's the windows context menu key). Perhaps you can give that a try, too.

Answer (score 1):

Set the XMODIFIERS variable to "":

$ env XMODIFIERS=""  java -jar your_java_application.jar

Or:

$ export XMODIFIERS=""

$ java -jar your_java_application.jar

But in the later case, XMODIFIERS variable will remain modified after exiting the java application, and may be other commands need it in its default value.

I learnt this trick here: https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5485348;jsessionid=AC90E67E77944B70A337D368B22A788A#5485348

Comment: Not only fixes problems with compose key. In my case it fixed problem with not working deadkey (Kubuntu 14.04).

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting the AWT_TOOLKIT environment variable this way

```
export AWT_TOOLKIT=MToolkit
```

Comment: Just tried, It does not work.

Comment: have you tried exporting the variable from a terminal and then launching your java application from the same terminal?

Comment: Tried, doesn't work :(